# Instagram OEmbed question - OAuthException 200 Provide valid app ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am facing an exception when trying to use Instagram OEmbed.

As stated in this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-oembed/

I sent an HTTP GET request to this endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CUsIdc5ql2b/&app
```

As stated in the documentation, I am using the "url" querystring parameter. However, I am getting an exception such as:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Provide valid app ID",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "Acr4on4TtEYPIc2RQwqNmDL"
    }
}
```

So there is an error clearly stating that I need to "Provide valid app ID". However, there is no information about how to provide that app ID. I've tried a few, including:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/v12.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CUsIdc5ql2b/
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{app_id}/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CUsIdc5ql2b/
```

with no luck. I am looking forward for solutions.

Comment: You need to supply an access token, via `access_token` parameter. And your app, that the token was issued for, needs to be approved for using this feature.

Answer (score 4):

As CBroe pointed out in the comments, you need a valid access token, which you could add at the end of your url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CUsIdc5ql2b?access_token=YOURTOKEN
```

You can look up further documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

Comment: Strange that the documentation doesn't mention this for all the fields where the app ID is required.

Comment: I've just started using the Meta SDK on Swift and I find the documentation is incomplete (it even seems outdated.) Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Since this did not solve the issue for me, I will post my solution.

One key difference is that I am using the SDK while the poster appears to be handling the url themselves.

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(
                access_token=credentials.password
            )
response = AdAccount(self.ad_account_id).get_insights(
                **request_kwargs
            )
```

If you're handling requests like this, make sure that you're specifying `access_token=xxx` as the token is a kwarg. Passing the token directly during initialization without specifying `access_token` will not throw an error until you actually make a request. However, most other issues with initialization DO throw errors. So it's very easy to get mislead into believing the initialization is not the issue when in fact it is.